# How to connect to mysql server located on computer 1 from computer 2 through the network?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a mysql server from another computer located on a different network than the network on which mysql server is running; all of this from java code using DAO classes.

First of all, if I'm on the same network of mysql server, I can connect to the database using the local ip `192.168.X.X`; I can't do that if my computer is connected to a different network.
I already did the following:

- granted access to a user (different from the root user) to access and modify tables in my DB.
- modified the file `mysqld.cnf` commenting out the line `bind-address` to receive connection from both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses
- created rules in both the firewall of my mysql server machine and my other machine allowing connection (in and out) on specific ports
- tried to use the website `canyouseeme`, which let you discover your "external" ip address and also allows you to ping a machine using the ip address, to ping ports on mysql server machine but I cannot ping them; the result is "Connection timed out" for every port

What should I do to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

if the computer 2 is connected to internet by a different modem or internet provider to the computer 1, you need open the 3306 port  in the modem cofig and redirect to the local ip of machine 2, the configuration is  according to your modem model

finally you need to use the external ip of network 2 as host in your project configuration and a user in mysql with host % or with external ip of network 1 (client)

ps. i suposse that comptuer 2 is where is running mysql

Answer (score -1):

Are you hosting the sql database? You can only connect to a server on a different network if you're hosting it somehow.

You could use something like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com). You will need to take of some security stuff and it needs a static IP.

The easiest thing though is to just buy a hosting domain and some memory space from a trusted company and throw all your stuff on there. Just google hosting service.

Comment: No, I'm not hosting the DB; what's the difference from hosting a DB and only allowing a connection to the 3306 port? Also, why in localhost I can access the DB but if I'm not in localhost I need to host the DB?

Comment: Maybe check this out: [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177235/connect-to-sql-server-over-internet)